# Odd function integrals?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If $f(x)$ is a odd function for $\int_{0}^4 f(x)dx=-3$

How to calculate or explain why there is not enough information to calculate it:

$\int_{-10}^0 f(x)dx $

$\int_{-4}^4|f(x)|dx$

Answer (score 1):

Int for the second one:

If $f(x)$ is odd it means $$f(-x) = -f(x)$$

Hence if you take the first integral you have and make the change $x\to -x$ you get

$$\int_0^4 f(x)\ \text{d}x \to \int_0^{-4} f(-x)\ \text{d}(-x) = -\int_{-4}^0 f(x)\ \text{d}x$$

This means that

$$\int_0^4 f(x)\ \text{d}x = -\int_{-4}^0 f(x)\ \text{d}x = -3$$

That is

$$\int_0^4 f(x)\ \text{d}x + \int_{-4}^0 f(x)\ \text{d}x = \int_{-4}^4 f(x)\ \text{d}x = 3 - 3 = 0$$

so

$$\int_{-4}^4 |f(x)|\ \text{d}x = 6$$

Remember that in general if $f(x)$ is odd, then

$$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)\ \text{d}x = 0$$

$$\int_{-a}^{a} |f(x)|\ \text{d}x = 2 F(a)$$

Where $F(a)$ is the primitive of $f(x)$ (The constant $c$ of integration is set to zero).

For the second case you may split it

$$\int_{-10}^0 = \int_{-10}^{-4}+ \int_{-4}^0$$

The second piece you know how it is

$$\int_{-4}^0 f(x)\ \text{d}x = 3$$

Hence

$$\int_{-10}^0 f(x)\ \text{d}x = \int_{-10}^{-4} f(x)\ \text{d}x + 3$$